# Set construction confusion

Tags: real-analysis

Let $S$ be an infinite bounded subset of $\mathbb R$. Now let's construct a set $T$ where,
$$T=\{x:x \textrm{ exceeds at most a finite number of elements of } S\}.$$
Is there any element of $T$ which is less than the infimum of $S$? If yes then how is it possible and if no then why?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. For example if $S=[1,2]$, then $T$ contains $0$, because $0$ exceeds *no* element of $S$.

In fact it will be true that $(-\infty,\inf S]\subset T$ for the same reason.